# Identify Whatsapp phone number when listing Twilio phone number

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

When listing our Twilio phone numbers using the Twilio REST API (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services/api/phonenumber-resource), a Whatsapp phone number appears as any other phone number.

There doesn't seem to be a specific capability for Whatsapp. We can only see voice, sms, mms and fax capabilities:

```
"capabilities": {
                "voice": true, 
                "sms": false, 
                "mms": false, 
                "fax": true
            },
```

What info can we use to identify a phone number as a Whatsapp phone number when using the Twilio REST API?

We tried using the Node Twilio module (v2.9.2 and v3.33.2).

Thanks,

Comment: Can I clarify a couple of points here? The API you point to here is the messaging service API so are you referring to phone numbers that are in a pool for a messaging service? Do you have an approved WhatsApp number (you are not working with the WhatsApp sandbox)?

Comment: Hi @philnash,
Thanks for the reply. Let me clarify my question.
We have a system that integrates with Twilio and allows our customers to send/receive messages and display them on an UI.
To automate things, our customers can add their phone numbers into our interface. To do so we list their phone numbers using the Twilio API (using their credentials) so they can pick the one they want to add.
And we're looking for a way to identify the phone numbers whatsapp-compatible.
Does it make sense?
Thanks,

Comment: Yes the number is approved and no we're not working with the sandbox.

Comment: I actually don't know, I'm going to check with the team behind this and will get back to you.

Comment: Ok thanks @philnash . Waiting for your reply :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm sorry to say that there is not currently a way to determine if a number in your account is enabled for WhatsApp. I am seeing if the channels and phone numbers team can collaborate to enable this information in the API, but it is not connected right now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @philnash

Comment: Hi Philnash, do you know if it's still not possible to check if the phone number is on whatsapp or not via the API?

Comment: @RobertSinclair not via the API, no. You can [view your approved WhatsApp senders in the console though](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/sms/senders/whatsapp-senders?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fsms%2Fwhatsapp%2Fsenders%3Fx-target-region%3Dus1).