# Is it possible to list Twilio WhatsApp Phone Numbers and Templates?

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

I am integrating with the Twilio API to send WhatsApp for Business messages. For the most part, so far everything has been straight forward. However, I foresee the need to be adding new WhatsApp phone numbers and templates in the future. While I have no problem using the Twilio UI to create these new resources, I was curious if there was a way to list the newly added phone numbers and templates in my app via their API. This would help ensure an update to the application wouldn't be needed each time that a new phone number or template is added.

I have found this other question from over a year ago which may indicate that listing phone WhatsApp phone numbers currently isn't possible. However, this question doesn't address listing templates and due to its age I also wanted to reask the community in case anything has changed. [Identify Whatsapp phone number when listing Twilio phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316100/identify-whatsapp-phone-number-when-listing-twilio-phone-number)

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I'm still waiting for Twilio to release some specific endpoint to list WhatsApp phone number. And I'm interested as well in an endpoint to list/create/update WhatsApp message templates.
According to the [Twilio node GH repository](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/CHANGES.md#2020-09-28-version-3494), something was done about it in v3.49.4 but I couldn't find anything when browsing the code :-(

Comment: Hey @philnash I hope you're doing fine. You replied to the other thread saying there was no update back in mid-2019. Any chance there is an update now? Also the [changes section](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/CHANGES.md#2020-09-28-version-3494) of the Node module says that something was done around the WhatsApp Templates API but I cannot find anything in the code. Could you shed some light here? Thanks.